# wrap divs within 2x2 table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four divs like below.

```
<div class='link'>...</div>
<div class='link'>...</div>
<div class='link'>...</div>
<div class='link'>...</div>
```

I want to place them in a 2x2 table.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td><div class='link'>...</div> </td>
  <td><div class='link'>...</div> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div class='link'>...</div> </td>
 <td><div class='link'>...</div> </td>
</tr>
```

with jquery on document ready

=======

Actually I need nX2 grid layout for those DIV's, so I made each two divs have same height using *jquery.css*. But on zoom+- that grid setting disturbed, so I thought table layout would be better, I found wrapping a solution but I don't know how to wrap divs within nX2 table.

// i tried below each at once, but four divs, four rows wrapping a single div, i need how to wrap first two divs in one row, and each div in one td , totally a table....

```
1st trial  $( ".linkbox" ).wrap( "<tr></tr>" );
2nd trial  $( ".linkbox" ).wrap( "<table></table>" );
3rd $( ".linkbox" ).wrap( "<td></td>" );
```

Comment: why cant you do it in the markup itself instead of doing it at dom ready?

Comment: here four is not fixed content wieght within divs is not predictable, each div height may vary with next div here i need nX2 grid-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do this: [<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/gk051qsr/)

```
var t = $(document.createElement('table'));
t.appendTo('#target');
var tr;
var counter=1;
$('.link').each(function(){
    console.log(this);
    if(counter%2!=0)
    {
    tr = $(document.createElement('tr'));
    tr.appendTo(t);
    }
    var td = $(document.createElement('td'));
    td.appendTo(tr);
    $(this).appendTo(td);
    counter++;
});
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="link">1</div></td>
            <td><div class="link">2</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="link">3</div></td>
            <td><div class="link">4</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## [Improved Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gk051qsr/1) by @Ruko

Comment: but why it is creating two tables first is empty next is filled with div's

Comment: @gani as i can see in demo under target div only one table is creating http://jsfiddle.net/gk051qsr/

Comment: I don't know why it was downvoted. @RokoC.Buljan thanks for improved demo i have added in my answer

Comment: @Roko - this is BRILLIANT! Now how can I add a colspan="2" if the last <tr> has only 1 <td>?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 $("div.link").replaceWith(function (i, val) {
    return $("<td/>", {
        "class": $(this).attr('class'),
        text: val
    });

});
$("td.link").each(function (i, val1) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        $("td.link:eq(" + i + "),td.link:eq(" + (i + 1) + ")").wrapAll($("<tr/>", {
            'class': 'trNew'
        }));
    }
});

$("tr.trNew").wrapAll("<table/>");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tLgmnrmy/1/)

Comment: `class :` is a reserved word therefore wrap into `"class" :`

Comment: good idea - replacing total div's with TD's and assinging same class nature

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , Thanks for noticed that reserved Class name, k i changed

Comment: `$("tr").wrapAll("<table/>")` is a bad idea. It'll traverse the entire DOM and unnecessarily wrap every single `<tr>` occurrence into a `<table>` element! http://jsfiddle.net/tLgmnrmy/2/ Try using a selector maybe?...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ,Ya you are right but i gave solution for which he was asked. now i changed the code , it will affect that specified class  only

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qaleti/1/edit)**

```
$(".link").wrapAll("<table/>").each(function(i) {
  $(this).wrap("<td/>");
  if(i%2) $(this).parent().prev().andSelf().wrapAll("<tr/>");
});
```

To explain the jQuery above:

- `$(".link").wrapAll("<table/>")` wrap them all into a table.
- Each still refers to the `DIV` so we can do an `each` and pass the `i` index value
- `$(this).wrap("<td/>")` wrap every DIV inside a TD element,
- After the above is done, our DIV is now inside a TD element, and if `i%2` is *truthy* means that we're currently inside the loop looking ad the ODD index element, so target the TD parent, target the previous TD element also, add to collection back the *self* and wrap them both into `TR`.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan ..Oh god.. i think he changed the his requirement,Initial time he did not ask like this..anyway sorry for wrong intimation :)

Comment: @Bala ...no, you need 1) more coffee (as I do) or 2) more sleep :) ;) no problem. just a note... the question was edited 1h ago so... and inside the revision (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26051832/revisions) there's no HTML code touch. :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this jQuery code:

```
var table = $('<table></table>').addClass('foo');

for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('bar');
     var td1 = $('<td></td>').addClass('bartd');
     var td2 = $('<td></td>').addClass('bartd');    
     row.append(td1);
    row.append(td2);
        var div="<div class='link'> hi div </div>";
    td1.append(div);
    td2.append(div);
    table.append(row);


}

$('html').append(table);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfa7Lh3g/3/

Comment: div's number may vary with huge inner text

Comment: here the table must be dynamic.. but you are statically doing that

Comment: @ohk Gani.You need table also dynamic.